# how to declare elements inside layout.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sdk

i have just sarted today playing around with android/sdk so sorry for the very stupid question, but i am learning.

I am using eclipse, I have put some code in to the java file of my project in order to connect an app to an adserver and it works fine, when i launch the app i get my ad banner.
i have imported android sdk, and the adserving provider sdk.

Now, i wanted to insert the banner in between some objects that i have created in the layout xml.

So, I have fragment_main.xml under layout folder where i put the below xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:opensdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myfirstapp"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/button_send"
       android:onClick="sendMessage" />


    <com.appnexus.opensdk.BannerAdView
       android:id="@+id/banner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:placement_id="YOUR PLACEMENT ID"
       android:auto_refresh="true"
       android:auto_refresh_interval="30"
       android:opens_native_browser="true"
       android:adWidth="320"
       android:adHeight="50"
       android:should_reload_on_resume="true"
       android:opens_native_browser="true"
       android:expands_to_fit_screen_width="false"
       />
```

now in correspondance of

```
    <com.appnexus.opensdk.BannerAdView
```

i get this error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'auto_refresh_interval' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adHeight' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expands_to_fit_screen_width' in package 
     'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'should_reload_on_resume' in package 
     'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'placement_id' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adWidth' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'opens_native_browser' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'auto_refresh' in package 'android'
```

So, where do i declare all those attributes? it must have somthing to do with this path: 
 xmlns:opensdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myfirstapp"

please let me know if you can help, and sorry for the poor info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<com.appnexus.opensdk.BannerAdView
       android:id="@+id/banner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:placement_id="YOUR PLACEMENT ID"
       android:auto_refresh="true"
       android:auto_refresh_interval="30"
       android:opens_native_browser="true"
       android:adWidth="320"
       android:adHeight="50"
       android:should_reload_on_resume="true"

       android:expands_to_fit_screen_width="false"
       />
```

to

```
  <com.appnexus.opensdk.BannerAdView
           android:id="@+id/banner"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           opensdk:placement_id="YOUR PLACEMENT ID"
           opensdk:auto_refresh="true"
           opensdk:auto_refresh_interval="30"
           opensdk:opens_native_browser="true"
           opensdk:adWidth="320"
           opensdk:adHeight="50"
           opensdk:should_reload_on_resume="true"

           opensdk:expands_to_fit_screen_width="false"
           />
```

Because you are using custom namespace for your banner view as

```
xmlns:opensdk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myfirstapp"
```

Comment: @ Simone if solved,please accept it,so it may help others also

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/sdk/Integrate+with+Android#IntegratewithAndroid-Showads) - 
In order to use appnexus you should do:

Step 1. Download the code.

If you have gitbash you could download it from github with this command `git clone git@github.com:appnexus/mobile-sdk-android.git`

You could also go to `https://github.com/appnexus/mobile-sdk-android` with your browser and download it in .zip file.

Step 2. Import appnexus SDK **as a library**

Import the sdk directory into your workspace **as a library** using the Android IDE.

Step 3. Add Activities

You must add the following activities to your **manifest** in order for the SDK to function:

```
<application
  <activity android:name="com.appnexus.opensdk.AdActivity" />
</application>
```

Step 4. Edit App Permissions

Edit your Android **manifest** to include the permissions needed by this app:

```
<!-- Add the permissions here... -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

As you probably know:

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` (required) - Grants the SDK permission to check for a live internet connection.

`INTERNET` (required) - Grants the SDK permission to access the internet.

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` (recommended) - Grants the SDK permission to access approximate location based on cell tower.

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` (recommended) - Grants the SDK permission to access a more accurate location based on GPS.

Wish you all the best!